# É correto usar "masculino" como substantivo?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, figuras-de-linguagem

Por vezes se encontram em notícias policiais (por exemplo [aqui](https://diariodosudoeste.com.br/seguranca/pm-prende-mulheres-com-drogas-em-pato-branco/), e [aqui](https://www.acidadeonline.com.br/post/corpo-de-um-masculino-%C3%A9-encontrado-na-lagoa-do-parque-de-eventos)) o uso da palavra "masculino" para denotar uma pessoa do sexo masculino (meu destaque):

> No local, os policiais abordaram **um masculino**, que estava com droga e alegou ter adquirido o entorpecente de duas mulheres.

> Corpo de **um masculino** é encontrado na lagoa do Parque de Eventos

**Pergunta**: Esse uso parece ser raro e não o encontrei em nenhum dicionário. Seria um jargão policial, ou apenas um erro?

Outras vezes, a palavra parece ser usada para denotar "masculinidade" ou "concepção de masculinidade", como [aqui](https://www.uol.com.br/ecoa/reportagens-especiais/joao-silverio-trevisan-o-masculino-esta-em-construcao-o-tempo-todo/#page1) e [aqui](https://revistamarieclaire.globo.com/Comportamento/noticia/2018/07/masculinidade-toxica-afeta-homens-e-mulheres-mas-eles-precisam-lidar-com-emocional.html):

> "O homem é alguém em crise permanente devido às definições que ele mesmo criou para si", diz. Assim, surgiu um homem violento, desafetuoso e intolerante. "O problema **do masculino**, no contexto do patriarcado, é que ele se julga o dono do pedaço."

> São comportamentos destrutivos, interna e externamente, conectados a uma visão de mundo que entende **o masculino** como superior ao feminino

**Pergunta**: Se trata de uma figura de linguagem, ou apenas liberdade poética?

Comment: Parece ser jargão de policia que se encontra também na mídias no Brasil: Acho que não vou colocar uma resposta. :) A  mulher relatou que o masculino que [era] alcoólatra e não possuía moradia fixa, teria invadido a residência que pertencente a um de seus irmãos, já há alguns dias. https://www.acidadeonline.com.br/post/corpo-de-um-masculino-%C3%A9-encontrado-no-ribeir%C3%A3o-areia

Comment: Pois é, @Lambie, com mais esse exemplo, começo a suspeitar que esses textos policiais estão apenas mal escritos...

Comment: Acho que as coisas podem evolucionar com o tempo. Porque senão teriam que haver escrito algo como: sujeito de sexo masculino. né? Será que dizem um feminino também?

Comment: Parece-me errado por não ter sentido completo. Eu não diria "As crianças compraram uma delícia." ou "A mãe encontrou uma gentil ao voltar para casa.". O que é uma delícia? Quem é gentil?

Comment: Paraíba masculina
Muié macho, sim sinhô :) Conhece a canção?

Comment: @Lambie :-) Sim, mas é um simples adjetivo.

Answer (score 1):

Em dicionários ([Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/masculino) e [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=masculino)), encontrei o sentido da palavra "masculino" como substantivo *apenas* no sentido de denotar qualidades de "macho"; portanto, os dois últimos exemplos na pergunta são válidos.

> O problema do **masculino**, no contexto do patriarcado, é que ele se julga o dono do pedaço.

> São comportamentos destrutivos, interna e externamente, conectados a uma visão de mundo que entende o **masculino** como superior ao feminino

No entanto, nada encontrei que indique esta palavra como sinônimo de "homem", "sujeito, do gênero masculino", "suspeito", ou nada que possa encaixa-se nestes contextos; minha conclusão é a mesma que @m26a (na seção de comentários): *Parece-me errado por não ter sentido completo.*